# How to search for objects properties inside arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with some objects

```
var arr = [{index: 1, type: 2, quantity: 1}, {index: 3, type: 1, quantity: 2}, {index: 1, type: 3, quantity: 3}];
```

Now I want to search my array if exists an object inside it with a given index and type. If exists, I add + 1 to the quantity property. If not, I add a new object with quantity of 1. I tried to use, $.grep and $.inArray but to no avail. What is the best way to search the properties in an array of objects?

tnx!

Comment: With [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), the `function` needs to `return` the result of the condition. The keyword isn't implicit.

Comment: Why not just use a for loop with if condition?

Comment: @true $.grep is cleverer than for loop? Why? It's not faster.

Comment: I like using [find from underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#find)

Answer (score 2):

For loop with if condition: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fkes3d7/5/)

```
var arr = [{index: 1, type: 2}, {index: 3, type: 1}];

var found = '';
for(item in arr){
    if(arr[item].index === 1 && arr[item].type === 2){
        found = arr[item];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function in grep you need to return the result of the test and also the result returned from grep is a new array. It does not modify the existing array.

I made a snippet:

```js
var arr = [{index: 1, type: 2}, {index: 3, type: 1}, {index: 1, type: 3}];

var result = $.grep(arr, function(e){
    return e.index === 1 && e.type === 3
});

alert(result[0].index + " " + result[0].type);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```